# Unsupported major.minor version 51.0 only from Eclipse

Tags: java, eclipse

Ok, so I have a common error but somewhat uncommon presentation.  If I right click on the project->export->WAR and output it to my jboss 7.1 deployment directory, it deploys fine, no errors. I have scanning enabled.

If I right click->Run As->Run on server, I get unsupported major.minor errors.  I have tried other suggestions of changing compiler to 1.6, still got the same errors though.  I've checked under the server setup in Eclipse and it's set to run as java-7-openjdk-amd64.  I've also tried changing that and compiler to 1.6, making sure they are both 1.7, set it to javaSE-1.7.  Same error.

Given that if I export the war file, I get no errors, I'm lead to believe that it's an Eclipse setup issue.  Any suggestion on what else it could be?

Comment: Class file version 51 means that the class is compiled with JDK 7. You need Java 7 or newer to run it. The fact that you get this error means that you are running it with Java 6 or older - there is no other reason why you get such an error. Check your setup once again.

Comment: Yes and as far as I can tell I'm telling it to compile and run under java 7, but I can only see those 2 places that is set.  Any suggestions where else it might be telling it to run under java 6?

Comment: While the process is running, use ps to find out the full location of which Java executable is being used. Sometimes indirection and other "helpers" can screw things up for you.

Comment: @nitind thanks for the suggestion.  It helped me track down where it wasn't pointing right, even though it said it was.

Answer (score 0):

Are you running eclipse with same JDK as server (java-7-openjdk-amd64)?

I saw same error in my project when eclipse was running (and generating classes) on jdk 1.7 while server (weblogic) was running with jdk 1.6. I had to change eclipse jdk to 1.6